# icecast2 and mpg123 not closing connection

Tags: icecast

I'm running `mpg123` `1.20.1` in a loop, connected to a local `icecast2` `2.4.0`stream created by Mopidy (Spotify).

`mpg123` finish normally after each song; looks like `icecast2` end-of-track  is interpreted as end-of-stream, so, I have a loop that restart `mpg123` at the end of each track.

The issue is that after a few hundred tracks, there are as many open connections! and `icecast2` stop advertising the stream.

There are no `mpg123` running processes.

How can I clean the open connections? Is this Icecast2 or mpg123 issue?

*Raspbian Jessie, Linux xxxx 4.1.15-v7+ #830 SMP Tue Dec 15 17:02:45 GMT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux*

Comment: This sounds like you should try to use a different player. If that player also complains about the stream, then you should review the source client (I'm not familiar with it). In general I'd suggest to use a supported codec like Opus or Vorbis.